# Testing context in React with react testing libraries

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm having a lot of issues and mishaps trying to test my context in my React App that relies mostly on react router dom.

I'm trying to make a simple test from a component that is inside the context provider, here is the component's code, named "GameSet" :

```
import { Form } from "react-router-dom";
import { forwardRef, useContext, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from "react";
import { SolutionContext } from "../contexts/SolutionContext";
import { gridItems, gameMapping } from "../utils/gameData";
import GameBlock from "./GameBlock";
import { solution as solutionMapping } from "../utils/gameData";

const GameSet = forwardRef(({ _ }, ref) => {

    const gameSet = useRef(null)
    const { currentSolution, handleSolutionContext } = useContext(SolutionContext)

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => gameSet.current)

    useEffect(() => {
        gameSet.current.reset()
    }, [currentSolution.currentID])

    const reset = () => {
        handleSolutionContext({
            currentPermutations: solutionMapping.currentPermutations,
            isValid: false
        })
        gameSet.current.reset()
    }

    const manageGameBlock = (gameBlock, val, i) => 
        gameBlock.value ? 
            <div key={`gridItem${i}`} className="gridItem gridGame">{gameBlock.value}</div>
            : <GameBlock 
                isValid={currentSolution.isValid}
                gameSet={gameSet} 
                value={currentSolution.currentPermutations[gameBlock.index]} 
                key={`gameBlock${val}`} 
                index={gameBlock.index}
            />

    return (
        <>
        <Form
            action={`newSolution/${currentSolution.currentID}`}
            method="post"
            ref={gameSet}
        >
            <div className="gridContainer">
                {gridItems.map((val, i) => {
                    return gameMapping[i + 1] ? 
                        manageGameBlock(gameMapping[i + 1], val, i)
                        : <div key={`blank-item${i}`} className="gridItem"></div>
                })}
            </div>
            <div className="formButtons">
                <button type="submit">Submit Solution</button>
                <button onClick={reset} data-testid="reset-button">Reset Game</button>
            </div>
        </Form>
        </>
    )
})

export default GameSet
```

And here is the code from the context "SolutionContext" :

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { solution } from "../utils/gameData";
import { getTimeStamp } from "../utils/utils";
import React from "react";

export const SolutionContext = createContext()

export function SolutionContextProvider({ children }) {

    const [currentSolution, setCurrentSolution] = useState({
        ...solution, 
        message: "Hello",
        updatedAt: getTimeStamp()
    })

    const handleSolutionContext = (data) => {
        let newData = {...currentSolution}
        Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => 
            newData = {...newData, [key] : value}
        )
        setCurrentSolution(newData)
    }

    return (
        <SolutionContext.Provider value={{ currentSolution, handleSolutionContext }}>
            {children}
        </SolutionContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And here is the simple test I'm trying to do :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { SolutionContextProvider } from '../contexts/SolutionContext';

import GameSet from '../components/GameSet';

describe('GameSet', () => {
  it('renders GameSet component', () => {
    render(<SolutionContextProvider><GameSet /></SolutionContextProvider>);

    expect(screen.getByTestId("reset-button")).toBeInTheDocument()
  });
});
```

And when i run `npm run test`, I have very long error message that I really have no idea on how to handle :

```
 FAIL  src/test/GameSet.test.jsx
  GameSet
    × renders GameSet component (386 ms)

  ● GameSet › renders GameSet component

    ReferenceError: React is not defined

      36 |             />
      37 |
    > 38 |     return (
         |     ^
      39 |         <>
      40 |         <Form
      41 |             action={`newSolution/${currentSolution.currentID}`}
```

and this one :

```
console.error
    The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef> component:
    
        at _ (C:\Users\fjtai\Desktop\MathSolver\FrontEnd\src\components\GameSet.jsx:8:31)
        at children (C:\Users\fjtai\Desktop\MathSolver\FrontEnd\src\contexts\SolutionContext.jsx:8:43)
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

       7 | describe('GameSet', () => {
       8 |   it('renders GameSet component', () => {
    >  9 |     render(<SolutionContextProvider><GameSet /></SolutionContextProvider>);
         |           ^
      10 |
      11 |     expect(screen.getByTestId("reset-button")).toBeInTheDocument()
      12 |   });
```

I really don't jnow what to do with this and how to solve these problems